# Limit Ordinal but Finite Cardinal

Tags: cardinals, ordinals

I had proved that infinite cardinal is limit ordinals.

but want to prove the inverse is false.

any ordinal which is limit ordinal but finite cardinal?

Comment: What about a limit ordinal that isn't a cardinal at all?

Comment: What does "infinite cardinal is limit ordinals" even mean?

Answer (score 1):

The converse of your statement is "A limit ordinal is an infinite cardinal".  You can disprove this with a limit ordinal that is not a cardinal, like $\omega + \omega$.  All the limit ordinals have infinite cardinality, but they are not all cardinals.